# If 'p-blockUI' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-module

I created a custom component that I use to block ui and it shows a progress spinner:

this is my html code:

```
<p-blockUI [blocked]="bloccaUI" >
    ...
</p-blockUI>
```

in my Module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        BlockUIModule,
        ProgressSpinnerModule

    ],
    declarations: [
        LoadComponent
    ],
    exports: [
       LoadComponent
    ]
})
export class ShareLoadModule { }
```

The problem is when I start the server, I read in my console:

```
If 'p-blockUI' is an Angular component and it has 'blocked' input, then verify that it is part of this module
```

and also:

```
If 'p-progressSpinner' is an Angular component and it has 'strokeWidth' input, then verify that it is part of this module
```

I don't know why because I put the module in the module export. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Hey, there. Can you please add a snapshot of the files/folder structure of your angular application, if possible.

Comment: @thisdotutkarsh are in the same folder